# SwiftUI custom ProgressIndicator made with `Circle()` and `trim` modifier shows full progress when 98% completion used in a small frame

Tags: swiftui

I use a custom ProgressIndicator made with `Circle()` and `trim` modifier as below.
Problem happens when I use `completed` to `0.98` which is close to full.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let remainingTimeStrokeColor: Color = .secondary
    let completedTimeStrokeColor: Color = .blue
    
    @State var completed: Double = 0.70
    // MARK: Use 0.98 to check the problem
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(remainingTimeStrokeColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 15))
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: completed)
                .stroke(completedTimeStrokeColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 15, lineCap: .square))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

The normal output with `completed = 0.75`:
[image: 0.75 completion]

**When it sets to `completed = 0.98`, then it looks like fully completed. This is my main problem.**

Output for `completed = 0.98`:
[image: 0.98 completion]

It shows fully completed when using 0.98 or more close to completed value.

**What I tried**

After many trials and error I figured out that if I don't use the `.frame(width: 200, height: 200)` or I use larger frame to show the progress view then I can see the 98% completion properly.

But according to my UI guide provided for my product I have to use this small size progress view.

Comment: Why `lineCap: .square`? Is that also one of the requirements? A square line cap causes the two ends of the line to look connected.

Comment: No, that's not a fixed requirement. Some other appropriate can be used.

Comment: Okay, so just delete that then. It should now work. The default is `.butt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Removing the .square worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you used [`.square`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cglinecap/square) for the blue circle's line cap.

> A line with a squared-off end. Core Graphics extends the line beyond the endpoint of the path for a distance equal to half the line width.

For a line width of 15, the stroke at both ends of the line extends beyond the line by 7.5 each, so the line's length is extended by 15 in total. This causes the "gap" that you expect between the two ends to disappear.

For a circle with radius 100, we can estimate the length of the "gap" that should be between the two ends of the line, by calculating:

```
tan(.pi * 2 * 0.02) * 100
```

This turns out to be about 12, which is less than 15.

Use the default `.butt` line cap instead.